# Update User Score if exists in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a user score system for a leaderboard using PHP and MYSQL and I am stuck now. I know it's something to do with  INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

It's an IPN and basically what it should do is grab the address and the amount and then add it to a new row in leaderboard if the address doesn't already exist. If the address does exist then it should pick that up and add the new amount on top of the existing amount in the row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the code that you're stuck on? We can work from there.

Comment: I had this but it isn't working. mysql_query("INSERT INTO leaderboard (id, address, amount) VALUES ('', '$sender', '$amount') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=amount+$amount") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: if ID is an autokey don't insert anything into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO leaderboard (id, address, amount) VALUES ('', '$sender', '$amount') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=amount+$amount") or die(mysql_error())
```

A few notes, you mysql is deprecated, you should use mysqli instead.

Also, the second use of $amount is vulnerable to SQL injection. Escape it using single quotes as well (you're better off using `mysql_real_escape_string` and then using single quotes or just use prepared statements).

if you have a PK that is autoincrementing, exclude it from the insert query (your code attempts to insert a empty string into an `INT` column, which won't work.) also note that if by address you mean IP address, it's possible for different users to have the same address and for one user to have multiple addresses. You may want to consider:

1. using the PK instead of address
2. find something else to uniquely identify users

Ignoring all of that to directly answer your question:

```
"INSERT INTO leaderboard (address, amount) VALUES ('$sender', '$amount') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=amount+'$amount'"
```

should work fine provided that address is required to be unique. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7b1/1

(if you don't add the unique index it won't work properly, you could always just identify the PK and use that instead)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I figured it out about 30 minutes ago. What I did was remove the id column and made address the primary key so the query would work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
UPDATE sometable
SET somerow = somerow + increment
WHERE otherrow = someid
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Will this also add a row if the address doesn't yet exist in the table? I need it to that as well.

Comment: Well right now I have `mysql_query("INSERT INTO leaderboard (id, address, amount) VALUES ('', '$sender', '$amount') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=amount+$amount") or die(mysql_error());` which doesn't work. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you at least insert an id? Since this is probably the primary key, it can't be empty. I should first try the query using some SQL IDE.

Comment: The ID is auto incremented. It's not even necessary in this situation to begin with. I just want a way that the IPN can add the new amount to the existing address' amount and if the address doesn't exist it will create a new row with the address and amount.

Comment: But if the id is automatically incrementing, the IDs are unique, and thus no given id will ever conflict with existing ones...

Comment: Yes but the thing is when the IPN is triggered the data pulled from it will not contain the same ID as the one already in the database. This is why I am basing it on address not ID.